# Is there any GLobal Subdivision Option for Cycles render engine?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, mesh, geometry, subdivision-surface

I am using Blender 3.5.1, and I am not able to find Global subdivision option.
I am using Cycles render engine.
For example I need to apply subdivision on all Geo's without adding Subdivision Modifier.

Comment: I think you need to set the render Feature Set to Experimental to enable that. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/render_settings/subdivision.html#subdivision